# Difference between the phrases "fake someone out", "fool someone", "deceive someone"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the phrases "fake someone out", "fool someone", "deceive someone"? On http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com I found the following examples of usage of the phrase "fake someone out":
"You really faked me out. I never would have guessed it was you. The student tried to fake out the teacher."

Somehow I don't feel I would use the phrase "fooled someone" in those contexts.
So what is the difference?

Comment: You don't think "You really fooled me. I never would have guessed it was you." is an acceptable sentence? Why not? Also, "fake someone out" is pretty informal/idiomatic.... and arguably dated, so I don't know that you'll hear it too often.

Comment: to fake out is to fool or deceive someone. Period. It is young-people-talk. Grade school. So I really don't know if it is still used, as I don't know any kids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I use the phrases, here are the differences:

If you **fake someone out**, you do something that makes them think you are going to do X, when you are actually going to do Y.

> I thought you were going to drive to the basket. When you pulled up
>   suddenly and took that 10 foot jump shot, you really faked me out.

When you **fool someone**, you get them to believe something which isn't true, and it usually is not serious but some kind of joke.

> Dressed up like that, you looked like an old man. You really fooled me
>   with that mustache and the gray wig.

When you **deceive** someone, you do something or say something that causes them to put their trust in you, and then you betray that trust in some (serious) way.

> He told her he was going away on a three-day business trip, but he deceived her. He was actually getting back together with his ex-girlfriend.

Other speakers may use these terms differently.